# Yeoman bower install vs npm install vs grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, yeoman, bower

This is my first time developing an AngularJS app and using the scaffolding tool Yeoman (http://yeoman.io/). I wanted to use fontawesome for some of my icons (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and I know I should use the command

```
bower install fontawesome
```

However, I also saw this article (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-font-awesome-vars) that talks about npm grunt install command below

```
npm install grunt-font-awesome-vars --save-dev
```

What is the difference there? I'm still a little fuzzy on how the variety of tools work and flow together. Could any Yeoman experts give me a low down when to use bower install, npm install, and the grunt commands so I would know the differences clearly and understand the flow? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Grunt** is a task automation tool that does very little straight out of the box. It does most of its work through plugging in grunt modules that perform specific tasks.

**grunt-font-awesome-vars** is a module for grunt (useless without grunt)

**bower** is a package manager.

**npm** is a package manager.

(I don't use Yeoman.  It's a scaffolding tool for setting up your project structure. I don't agree with its opinions on where things should go, so I don't fool with it. I configure grunt and bower manually)

### Quick and dirty:

install node with npm.
Then from your console, (Developer Command Prompt for VS2013, Bash, or whatever you use)
run the following commands

```
npm install grunt --save
npm install bower --save
npm grunt-font-awesome-vars --save
```

bower doesn't need grunt. grunt doesn't need bower. grunt doesn't need grunt-font-awesome-vars but grunt-font-awesome-vars needs grunt.

With the way my work flows, I use npm to manage package dependencies that I want to automate with grunt. I use bower to manage the versions of my client dependencies.

### More information:

There's a "Yo, Dawg" to describes bower that comes to mind when someone asks the difference between it and npm.

> "Yo, Dawg. We heard you *really* like packages so we installed a
>   package manager inside your package manager."

Basically, bower is just another package manager. It is installed with npm (which is a separate package manager)

I use npm for managing tooling and server dependencies (like grunt, grunt modules, sass, etc...things I potentially want to be automated) and bower for *functional, client specific* dependencies (like angular, jquery, etc...things that I potentially want to keep up to date with current version)

Installing through bower will utilize your bower.json.  Installing through npm will utilize your package.json.

```
npm install grunt-font-awesome-vars --save-dev
```

will install grunt-font-awesome-vars *as well as* update your package.json with a devDependency(the --save-dev flag does that) so that it is automatically installed any time you perform an

```
npm install
```

if you change that command to

```
npm install grunt-font-awesome-vars -g
```

it will install grunt-font-awesome-vars to your node install location (indicated by your PATH system variable) and be available to all node instances.

### Edit to answer question from comments

> Asked: Also, why is there the need to have the install command as 'grunt-font-awesome-vars -g'

grunt-font-awesome-vars is the name of a module for grunt that is deployed as a node package.  You install grunt modules with the "npm install" command. -g is a flag that instructs npm to install the requested package to global space, by making it available through your PATH variable.  The only things that I currently have installed globally are http-server, bower, and karma.  If you don't have packages installed globally, then you will have to have performed an "npm install" of that package at the current working directory in order to execute the commands of that package.  For instance, http-server is a node module and is executed command line just like any other console application.  In this case, the command "http-server" will start a local http server anywhere you want to serve a site from.  If I install it to my PATH, I can run http-server from anywhere I want without having to do anything special.  If you don't install it to your PATH, then the http-server executable must be in the directory in which you are wanting to run it.  I install it globally so that I never have to "npm install" it again.  Most things you will want to package with your project and that you can do with the --save flag rather than the -g (or --global ...they do the same thing) flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you go into some more detail on the difference between bower.json vs package.json. Is the main difference that if I download via bower it won't be downloaded when I call 'npm install'? Is there a 'bower install' command that is the same as 'npm install' but utilizing the bower.json file instead? Also, why is there the need to have the install command as 'grunt-font-awesome-vars -g'? Does npm use grunt to download packages or how are they realated?

Comment: correct.  you install from your bower.json with the command "bower install"  You install from your package.json with the command "npm install." You automate injection of your bower dependencies into your html templates with something like the grunt-bower-install grunt module. The last statement is to drive home the point that grunt is an automation tool. You 'plug' modules into it and configure them to do your bidding.

Comment: I just realized that you asked several questions in that comment.  The "correct" goes to the first question.  Second question, that is correct.  Third question, I'll update to answer.  Fourth question, the answer is not to my knowledge (I know of no grunt modules that specifically, automatically drives package management)  You *could* use the grunt-shell module and execute "npm-update" which will update all of your node modules, but I find it undesirable to pull new versions automatically. Executing "npm-update" manually will allow you to perform an "opt-in" update of your dependencies.